# Is there a reason not to print uint64_t directly?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am looking into printing out the MAC address of an ESP32 board. The Arduino Examples define it by the following:

```
uint64_t chipid=ESP.getEfuseMac();//The chip ID is essentially its MAC address(length: 6 bytes).
Serial.printf("ESP32 Chip ID = %04X",(uint16_t)(chipid>>32));//print High 2 bytes
Serial.printf("%08X\n",(uint32_t)chipid);//print Low 4bytes.
```

However, I found the following way to do it:

```
  uint64_t chipId = ESP.getEfuseMac();
  Serial.printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", chipId);
```

The second way is obviously more verbose, however, while looking online, I never found such an example with the Arduino boards. Is there a memory issue that way and if so - what?

Comment: because 64bit printf was not supported some time ago. https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/52

Comment: @Juraj, please don't answer in the comments. Please create an answer to the question so it can be accepted and upvoted. Qs and As are also not so fleeting as comments on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64-bit printf() support was added end of 2016 (I think) and the example seems to predate that. The `PRIx64` is the correct way to print a 64-bit number.

See also  https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/52